# How do I fix this error?: "use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class"

Tags: swift, realm

Here is my class:

```
class Sentence: RLMObject {
    dynamic var words = RLMArray(objectClassName: Word.className())
    dynamic var content = ""

    init(content: String){
        super.init(object: content)
        self.content = content
        let wordArray = makeWordTokens(content)
    }
```

When I try to create a Sentence object like this...

```
let sentence = Sentence(content: "你好吗？")
```

...I get the following runtime error:

```
fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class 'MyApp.Sentence'
```

Why does it tell me I haven't implemented the initializer? What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, but *full* reproducing example?

Comment: I, noob, am sorry, but I don't quite understand your request. What more do you need to see?

Comment: Well, I can't take your code and paste it into a Playground to reproduce the problem, because I don't know what RLMObject, RLMArray, makeWordTokens, etc. The best way of getting people to help you is to narrow down your problem to the simplest example that other people can then reproduce easily on their machines. It shouldn't be too hard to take what you've got, cut out anything that's not relevant to the problem, and get a complete reproduction in a short page of code. (Also, while doing that, you often figure out what's wrong for yourself.) See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: Oh, ok. thanks. I am pretty sure this won't work in the playground because you can't use Realm.io in a playground - https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/938

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to be a Playground. But at the moment I'd struggle to reproduce your problem. Can you at least temporarily chip away at any dependencies that you can? e.g. does the problem still occur if you don't have the call to makeWordTokens? Can you remove anything else? Basically, the fewer lines of code and the fewer external things mentioned in that code that can still reproduce the problem, the better.

Comment: Yes, it still occurs if I remove the call to makeWordTokens().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you implement designated initializer, subclass doesn't inherit superclass designated initializers. see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_331).

`RLMObject`'s `init(object:)` [calls `self.init()`](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/Realm/RLMObject.mm#L50):

```
- (instancetype)initWithObject:(id)value {
    self = [self init];
```

but `Sentence` does not inherits `init()` initializer. That's why you see the error.

I think [`convenience` initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_325) solves your problem:

```
class Sentence: RLMObject {

    convenience init(content: String){
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
        self.init(object: content)
//      ^^^^^

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: That helps somewhat. Thanks. Now I am getting another error: ```Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid value '<null>' for property 'content''``` How can it be null if we just initialized it?

Comment: That is not related to this question. and I don't know because I've never used Realm.io. But, I think `init(object:)` expects `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, not `String`.

Answer (score 2):

`init()` must be implemented when creating Realm models in Swift. This is because Realm uses Swift's `reflect()` for introspection to determine what properties are in your models, which requires Realm to create an instance of your model.

Simply creating an empty `init()` should work fine.

There's also the matter of no providing an appropriate `object` argument to `super.init(object:)`. The `RLMObject(object:)` initializer expects the `object` argument to be either an array or dictionary of properties to set. In your case, you're passing it a `String`.

Comment: This GitHub issue contains workarounds: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1101#issuecomment-93574402